# Blazor routing on condition

Tags: c#, blazor, blazor-server-side

**Context**

I'm using BlazorServer to develop a web application. Before the user can do anything on my web application he has to select a dataset on which he wishes to work on. Therefore, I'm trying to redirect the user to a selection page as long as no selection was made. I'm storing the selection in a service that is added via `AddScoped` to the application.

**Approach**

In `App.razor` I'm using the `OnNavigateAsync` event of the `Router` component to detect when a navigation happens. `storage` is a service that is injected into `App.razor`.

```
@inject NavigationManager NavigationManager
<Router AppAssembly="@typeof(Program).Assembly" OnNavigateAsync="@OnNavigateAsync">
</Router>
@code {
    private void OnNavigateAsync(NavigationContext args)
    {
        if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(storage.dbName))
            NavigationManager.NavigateTo("/");
    }
}
```

**Problem**
When starting the app this leads to a "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.NavigationException" which is not closer specified.

**How can I redirect the user based on the value of `storage.dbName`?**

Comment: You need to inject the Navigation Manager to use it.

Comment: @BrianParker I did so. This is only a fragment of the code that I considered necessary. I'm going to add that line. Thanks for pointing out!

Comment: Do you need to do it via nav? Can you not just have a "if the model.ChosenDataSet == null then render the chooser component else render the dataset editor componnet" ?

Comment: @CaiusJard Where would you put it? This condition applies for my whole web page, so putting it inside a specific component seems not to be the perfect solution.

Comment: Your question doesn't contain any markup so it's hard to advise but i was thinking of e.g. a razor page entry of eg `@if(model.ChosenDataset == null){ <DataSetChooserComponent @bind-DataSet="@model.ChosenDataSet" /> } else { <DataSetRenderer @DataSource = model.ChosenDataSet/>... ` - when model's property is set the page will stop rendering the chooser and start rendering the viewer